# AWS Batch permits only 32 concurrent jobs in array configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I'm running some AI experiments that requires multiple parallel runs in order to speed up the process.

I've built and pushed a container to ECR and I'm trying to run it with AWS Batch with an Array size of 35. But only 32 starts immediately while the last three jobs remains in the RUNNABLE state and don't start until one job has finished.

[image]

I'm running Fargate Spot for cost-saving reasons with 1 vcpu and 8GB RAM.

I looked at the documentation but there are no Service Quota Limits to increase regarding the size (the max seems to be 10k) neither in Fargate, ECS and AWS Batch.

What could be the cause ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad. The limit is actually imposed in the Compute Environment associated with the jobs.
[image]

I answered myself hoping to help somebody in the future.

Comment: You can increase this limit to any number of vCPU's.